# An example of a mapping $\eta\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ such that $\eta(x)=n$ has infinitely many solutions for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, examples-counterexamples

Suppose I have the mapping $\eta\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ such that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ the equation $\eta(x)=n$ has infinitely many solutions. I saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1180666/showing-a-mapping-has-infinitely-many-solutions) which is basically the same thing, but some of the examples/solutions are a bit over my head.

I was wondering if someone might know of a closed-form definition for $\eta(x)$ that is relatively simple that accomplishes the goal at hand. There doesn't seem to be anything all that simple even though it is easy to understand the problem. I was thinking of trying to use a trigonometric function, the floor or ceiling function, something modular, etc., but nothing is working out very nicely. Any examples of some mapping definitions that might work out nicely?

Comment: The first thing for me that comes to mind is some modification of $\left \lceil{tan x}\right \rceil$, but I haven't had enough time to verify

Comment: @Brenton That's what I was thinking about a little while ago, but I think the issue is that $x\in\mathbb{N}$. If we had $\eta\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{N}$, then I think that might work, but I don't think it will work as is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\eta(x) = \lfloor |\tan(x)| \rfloor$ will do, because (1) $\tan$ is periodic with period $\pi$ and maps the set $D = [0, \pi/2) \cup (\pi/2, \pi)$ continuously onto $\mathbb{R}$ and (2) for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, reduction *modulo* $\pi$ maps $\{m \in \mathbb{N} \mathrel{|} m > n\}$ onto a dense subset of $D$. Statements (1) and (2) imply that for any real number $y$ and any given $\epsilon > 0$, $|\tan(m) - y| < \epsilon$ for infinitely many $m \in \mathbb{N}$. So given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, take $y = n + 1/4$ and $\epsilon = 1/8$, to get infinitely many $m\in\mathbb{N}$ for which the floor of $\tan(m)$ is $n$.

Comment: Okay. I'm interested in really understanding this answer because this is actually what I originally had in mind, but I thought this would not work because we have $\eta\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ instead of $\eta\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{N}$. Doesn't that cause an issue? It doesn't seem like we could actually map to all values of $\mathbb{N}$ using only values of $\mathbb{N}$ as inputs into $\tan(x)$. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: @KevinChurch How might the function definition be fixed up then?

Comment: I have tried to spell it out in a bit more detail.

Comment: Hm. I guess I'm just getting confused with notation now. It seems like you're saying to define $\eta(x)=\lfloor|\tan(x)|\rfloor=n$ where this will have infinitely many solutions. Sorry I'm a bit dense--no pun intended.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by $\{m:\mathbb{N}\mid m>n\}$ either. Did you mean $m\in\mathbb{N}$? Otherwise, I'm not sure how that fits in precisely.

Comment: I have tried to align my notation with yours.

Comment: Thank you for being patient. I think I'm starting to see the light. Could you explain how your definition works when, say, $n=87$? How are there infinitely many solutions to this?

Comment: Because there are infinitely many $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $87\frac{1}{8} < \tan(m) < 87\frac{3}{8}$ and for all of those values of $m$, the floor of $\tan(m)$ is $87$.

Comment: I think I *finally* get why your solution works. Part of it is because $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $m>n$, where $n\in\mathbb{N}$; hence, since $\mathbb{N}$ has infinitely many elements, then thinking *modulo* $\pi$ will guarantee us *infinitely* many $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that we can still "cover $\mathbb{R}$" or map onto $\mathbb{R}$ by using the floor of $\tan(m)$ right?

Comment: You mean "map onto $ \mathbb{N}$", I think. But, yes, I think you've got the idea.

Answer (score 8):

Let for any $x\in \mathbb N$, $x>1$ $\eta(x)$ be the number of factors in factorization of $x$ in the product of prime numbers. We define $\eta(1)=1$. Then $\eta$ satisfies your conditions. Here $\mathbb N=\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$.

Another variant: [Infinite Hotel](http://palmer.wellesley.edu/~ivolic/pdf/Classes/MATH225ComboFall08/ExtraordinaryHotel-Lem.pdf).

Third variant. For $x\in\mathbb N$ let $\eta(x)=1+\max\{k\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq  0}:2^k\mid x\}$, in other words, $\eta(x)=1+$ the length of "zero tail" of $x$ in binary expansion of x. Instead of two, you can take any other natural number greater than $1$ (inspired by HowDoIMath).

After all, I found [Hilbert's Hotel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this one. Are you talking about the number of prime factors of $x$?

Comment: @Farnight Let $1<x\in\mathbb N$. Then we can find primes $p_1,\ldots,p_l$ such, that $x=p_1\cdot\ldots\cdot p_l$. We define $\eta(x)=l$. If $x=1$, then $\eta(x)=1$.

Comment: And $\eta_0(x)=\eta(x)-1$ if you have $0\in\mathbb{N}$, with $\eta_0(0)=42$.

Comment: @AlexW What if $n=6$? You would have $\eta(x)=6$. Are you saying, then, $x=p_1\cdot p_2=2\cdot 3=6$? Could you give an example? I'm not entirely sure I understand your answer *just* yet.

Comment: @veritas $6=2\cdot 3$. Here we have 2 prime factors, hence $\eta(6)=2$. Another example. Let $x=4!$. Then $x=2\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 2$ - $4$ prime factors. Hence $\eta(x)=4$.

Comment: @AlexW Oh, I see. So I would also have, say, $\eta(143)=2$ and so on right? And this is how the "infinity" part kind of works right?

Comment: @egreg Why $42$? whether it is connected with "The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything"? )

Comment: @AlexW Why not? Choose the number you like best. `;-)` But the ultimate answer is as good as any other.

Comment: @veritas Yes, all right.

Answer (score 8):

$d(n)=$ the number of divisors of $n$.

Note that $d(p^{n-1})=n$ for all primes $p$.

Comment: This seems like it might be the easiest way to look at it. How would $\eta(x)$ be defined then? Depends on the prime number under consideration right?

Comment: @veritas $\eta(x)=d(x)$. The standard formula is $\eta(x)=(a_1+1)...(a_k+1)$ where $x=p_1^{a_1}... p_k^{a_k}$.

Answer (score 6):

You could choose $$\eta(0,1,2,3,4,5,6\dots)= (\color{red}0,\color{blue}{0,1},\color{orange}{0,1,2},\color{green}{0,1,2,3}\dots)$$

i.e:
$\eta(0)=\eta(1)=0$ and

$$
\eta(n+1) =
  \begin{cases}
   \eta(n)+1 & \text{if } \eta(n)\leq \max\{\eta(0),\dots,\eta(n-1)\} \\
   0       & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
$$

It's easy to see that $\eta(x)=n$ has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Is this any different than G. H. Faust's answer on the other thread (the linked to question)? I feel like there must be a somewhat simple mapping definition lurking out there. Just don't see it. At all.

Comment: @veritas Sorry about that. I didn't check the other thread before posting. But the formula for $\eta$ is made explicit in here. (recursive definition)

Comment: My answer's equivalent. Just not recursive

Answer (score 4):

Let $x\in\mathbb{N}$, and let $\eta(x)$ be the number of times the digit 1 appears in the binary expansion of $x$.

For any $n$, the equation $\eta(x)=n$ has infinitely many solutions. For instance, if $n=4$, then the numbers with the binary expansions $1111$, $11110$, $\ldots$, $111100\ldots 00$ are all mapped to $4$.

Notice that in this example, we have $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$, i.e. $0\not\in\mathbb{N}$.

As suggested in the comments, one can also let $\eta(x)-1$ be the number of times the digit $1$ appears in the *decimal* expansion of $x$.

Comment: Observe that the function $\eta$ must map the natural numbers into natural numbers...+1

Comment: @k1.M I think you changed the content of this answer somewhat by having the $-1$.

Comment: Yes that was needed, because the function maps natural numbers to itself, hence by new definition $\eta(2)-1=0$ which means that $\eta(2)=1$.

Comment: @k1.M Aren't you then claiming $\eta(1)=0$, a number that is not a natural number?

Comment: Observe that we have $\eta(1)-1=1$, hence $\eta(1)=2$.

Comment: @k1.M didn't you render the example invalid, then, when $n=4$?

Comment: I edited the answer again....this is a good answer to your question...

Comment: @k1.M I think I may see it now. Whent $n=1$, since the expansion is binary, we would have 0, 00, etc right? I think this may be the simplest answer...if, indeed, I understand it now.

Comment: @k1.M Perhaps I'm sleepy, but I'm not quite sure what the objection is. Is it because you include $0$ in the natural numbers? I didn't in my definition of $\eta$. Also, I don't understand your comment about $\eta(2)-1=0$, since $2$ is $10$ in binary, and thus $\eta(2)-1=1$.

Comment: I wrote your answer in decimal form to be calculated easily...

Comment: @HowDoIMath I'm not quite sure what the objection is either, but now I am confused. :/

Comment: @k1.M Now you changed it to decimal expansion at the top and yet the answer then talks about binary expansion. The whole thing is confused now it seems.

Comment: @HowDoIMath Unless I'm mistaken...it seems like your original answer was fine. After all, if a number is a natural number, then it must be *at least* $1$, in which case the binary expansion is simply $1$. How is your original answer flawed? What am I missing?

Comment: @veritas First, I believe that k1.M includes $0$ in the natural numbers. Hence the need for subtracting 1 from $\eta$. Second, he changed the binary expansion to a decimal expansion, but missed changing it later in the post. Let me rewrite my post to clear up any confusion and include these ideas.

Comment: @HowDoIMath Thank you. :) Btw, I am using the convention that $\mathbb{N}$ does *not* include $0$, something I maybe should have stated in the original post. With $\mathbb{N}$ not including $0$, I think your original answer is fine and makes sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A_{1}$ be the set of all positive integer whose lowest prime factor is 2 , $A_{2}$ be the set of all positive integer whose lowest prime factor is 3 , $A_ {3} $ be the set of all positive integer whose lowest prime factor is 5 and so on....clearly  $A_{i}$ are infinite and mutually disjoint. Now define $\eta \colon \mathbb{N} \rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ by
$ \eta (x) = 1 $  if $ x \in A_{1}\cup\{1\}$

= 2 if $ x\in A_{2}$
   = 3 if $ x \in A_{3}$
   = 4 if $ x \in A_{4}$
 and so on..
Note that this is well defined map. How? .....this works and simple

Comment: This is almost completely indecipherable.

Comment: Ok...i made typing mistake. Now clear?

Comment: A good idea. I also thought about it )

Answer (score 3):

Here is another simple example:

Write $n$ in binary (or any other basis) and define $\eta$ to be the erasing of the first digit.

This has the desired property because for all integers $x$, as long as $2^m >x$ we have 
$$\eta(2^m+x) =x$$

Answer (score 2):

$\eta\left(x + \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right) = x$ where $x \leq n$.

Equivalently, $\eta(x) = x - \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ where $n$ is such that $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} \leq x < \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$, $\therefore n = \lfloor\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{8x+1} - 1)\rfloor$

This is a nonrecursive formulation of Farnight's answer.